# Is there any way to inherit settings in the .config file from a subassembly?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to inherit settings in the .config file from a subassembly?

Example:

- Imagine I have an assembly .NET that does something like connect to a database, or a remote WCF service. This assembly is called "Connect.dll", and its config file is "Connect.dll.config".
- This sub assembly is called from the main program, "main.exe", its config file is "main.exe.config".
- Is there some way to import the settings from "connect.dll.config" into "main.config", without having to copy the appropriate .xml lines in in by hand?

Comment: My reason for this question? This would make deployment of a standalone assembly much, much easier. Alternatively, if there is some programmatic way of importing the .config file for the subassembly, I'm all ears.

Comment: You could use `configSection` attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/a/480750/750216

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is however possible to load configuration from the "Connect.dll.config" manually using [the ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager_methods.aspx) API.