# Is there a good web.config editor?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, web-config, editor

I'm wondering if there are any web.config editors for ASP.NET applications out there that are extensible.  We have various architectures being used in this application: Enterprise Library, WCF services--which makes all sorts of crazy changes when you update your code that aren't necessary, a workflow library, Strongly Typed DataSets, custom web controls, we have custom web.config sections (for LDAP queries and SSRS subscription custom settings, custom .NET rule engine config sections), SMTP settings, etc...  The file is 37 pages long!  Enterprise Library has a nice web.config editor, but it only shows the information in Enterprise Library.  It would be nice to have a nice GUI to see the web.config and to show what each section is for, and to edit it without doing so in a text editor.  And even if it didn't understand what a section was, it would be cool to write an extensible control to interpret what the properties are in that XML section.

Comment: As an aside from the actual question you asked, have you considered [breaking up your web.config into multiple files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480538/use-xml-includes-or-config-references-in-app-config-to-include-other-config-files)?

Comment: it used to be..  the new Enterprise Library 5.0 config editor doesn't work with split up files anymore.  The old one did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a tool like [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html)?

Comment: I couldn't find anything better.  So I gave you some SO money.  :-)